# How do I make text appear at the bottom of a <td> using CSS and <div>?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something very simple here.
I just want to make my text appear at the bottom of a table cell that it is in.
But I want to do it in CSS, not in the html  tag itself.

Why doesn't the code shown below work? In the example below, my Text appears in the middle of the cell, not at the bottom. Why?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myClass2 {
        color:red;
        font-weight:bold;        
        font-style:italic;            
        vertical-align:text-bottom;        
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<table bgcolor="black" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="white" class="myClass1" width="300">        
            <div class="myClass2">            
                Why won't this align at the bottom?
            </div>                    
        </td>
        <td height="100" bgcolor="white">
               Something very tall here.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `tr td{vertical-align:bottom}`

In your code you have given `vertical-align` to div not for `td` that is why it is not aligning.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pbAFQ/2/)**

---

If you want to align only first cell text then add the below code

```
td:first-child {vertical-align:bottom}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pbAFQ/4/)**

---

Using position values

```
 .myClass2 {
        color:red;
        font-weight:bold;        
        font-style:italic;            
        vertical-align:text-bottom;        
        text-align: center;
    background:green; 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0
    }
tr td{position:relative}
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/pbAFQ/6/)**

Comment: The problem is that I cannot give it generically to all <td>s because I only want this to occur in <td>s in which this <div> exists. And I don't know apriori which ones those are.

Comment: @user1742777 in that case you can use position values. check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can align text by using  `vertical-align` property

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<style>
    .myClass2 {
            color:red;
            font-weight:bold;        
            font-style:italic;            
            vertical-align:bottom;        
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <table bgcolor="black" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="white" class="myClass2" width="300">        
                <div class="myClass2">            
                    Why won't this align at the bottom?
                </div>                    
            </td>
            <td class="myClass2" height="100" bgcolor="white">
                   Something very tall here.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you should use :

```
<style type="text/css">
.myClass1 {
position:relative;
}
.myClass2 {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;        
    font-style:italic;  
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;        
}
</style>

<table bgcolor="black" border="1">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="white" class="myClass1" width="300">        
        <div class="myClass2">            
            Why won't this align at the bottom?
        </div>                    
    </td>
    <td height="100" bgcolor="white">
           Something very tall here.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already able to trigger the div to on or off. If you just need styling then you could use a code similar like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myClass1 td .myClass2 {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;        
    font-style:italic;            
    vertical-align:text-bottom;        
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<table bgcolor="black" border="1" class="myClass1">
<tr>
    <td height="100" bgcolor="white" width="300">
           Something very tall here.
        <div class="myClass2">            
            Why won't this align at the bottom?
        </div>                    
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```